# Find the matrix of linear operator $T$ with respect to B, B'

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

*I'm currently working on the following problem:*

Let $T$ be the linear operator on $\mathbb{C}^2$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,0)$. Let $B$ be the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$ and let $B'={(1,i), (-i, 2)}$. What is the matrix of $T$ relative to the pair $B, B'$?

*Now I had no idea what the writer meant by "relative to the pair $B, B'$", so I figured I'd basically make a guess and go from there. My solution became the following:*

Note that $$[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Let $P$ be the matrix which describes $B'$, then $$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&-i\\i&2\end{bmatrix}$$
We're now interested in finding $P^{-1}$, to that end we'll use Gauss-Jordan elimination to get:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-i&&1&0\\i&2&&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}1&-i&&1&0\\0&1&&-i&1\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&&2&i\\0&1&&-i&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Which gives us $$P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}2&i\\-i&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $$[T]_{B'}=P^{-1}[T]_BP=P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&-i\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-2i\\-i&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

*My first question of course, is whether this is the solution the exercise was asking about? Or if now, what should I be thinking about instead?*

Comment: My guess is that, they mean the matrix which takes an input in the $B$ coordinates, applies $T$, then converts to the $B'$ basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the matrix of your operator with respect to the bases $B,B'$ (with $B$ used for the domain and $B'$ used for the codomain) you need to calculate $T(e_i)$ for each of the basis elements of $B$ and represent the result in terms of the elements of $B'$. Then, put the resulting coefficients as columns of the matrix. In your case, we have

$$ T(1,0) = (1,0) = 2(1,i) - i(-i,2),\\
T(0,1) = (0,0) = 0(1,i) + 0(-i,2) $$

so

$$ [T]_{B'}^{B} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$